# CSR and BFS always finds with 0 steps

Tags: c, graph, breadth-first-search

I am trying to create a program that creates a graph in the CSR (Compressed Sparse Rows) format with two arrays where one array is the offset of each node and the second one are the edges. The data are read from a file, and I am using dictionary/map to reserve on memory. Then, it asks for the node and edge and using the BFS way of searching a graph, it must print if a path exists. However, no matter what I type, the program always returns that it found but does not print that it exists and the steps are 0.

The file looks like this:

```
737 6340
1740    1199
1738    1199
1738    1811
1738    2085
1739    1199
1741    214
1741    1199
1741    1419
1741    1496
1741    1723
```

The program looks like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef struct{
  int* num;
  int size;
  int top;

} stack;


int nodesdoublesize(int** array,int n){
  int* new_array=malloc(n*2*sizeof(int));
  if(new_array==NULL){
    printf("Error allocating memory\n");
    abort();
  }
  n*=2;
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    new_array[i]=(*array)[i];
  }
  free(*array);
  *array=new_array;
  return n;
}
void stack_destroy(stack *s){
  free(s->num);
  free(s);
}




int hashcmp(const void *a,const void *b){
  return ( *(int*)a - *(int*)b );
}

int hashdoublesize(int** hash,int nodes){
    int* new_array=malloc(nodes*2*sizeof(int));
    if(new_array==NULL){
        printf("Error allocating memory\n");
        abort();
    }

    for(int i=0;i<nodes;i++){
        new_array[i]=(*hash)[i];
    }
    nodes*=2;

    free(*hash);
    *hash=new_array;
    return nodes;
}

typedef struct {
    int start;
    int end;   
} path;






stack* stack_create(){  
  stack *s=malloc(sizeof(stack));
  if(s==NULL){
    printf("Error allocating memory for stack\n");
    abort();
  }
  s->top=0;
  s->size=10;
  s->num=malloc(s->size*sizeof(int));
  if(s->num==NULL){
    printf("Error allocating memory\n");
    abort();
  }
  return s;
}





int cmp(const void *a,const void *b){
    int l=((path*)a)->start;
    int r=((path*)b)->start;

    if(l>r)
        return 1;
    if(l<r)
        return -1;
    else
        return 0;
}

int doublesize(path** array,int n){
    path* new_array=malloc(n*2*sizeof(path));
    if(new_array==NULL){
        printf("Error allocating memory\n");
        abort();
    }

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        new_array[i]=(*array)[i];
    }
    free(*array);
    *array=new_array;
    n*=2;
    return n;

}
int bfs(int* arraynodes,int* arrayedges,int n,int st,int end){
  stack *s=stack_create();
  int color[n];
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    color[i]=-1;
  }
    color[st]=0;
  s->num[s->top]=st;
  while (s->top!=0){
    for (int i = arraynodes[st]; i < arraynodes[st+1];i++){
      if (color[i]==-1){
        color[i]=0;
        s->top++;
        s->num[s->top]=i;
        if(s->top==s->size){
         s->top=nodesdoublesize(&s->num,s->size);
        }
        if(s->num[s->top]==end){
          printf("Exists\n");
          return 0;
        }
      }
      s->top--;
    color[i]=1;

    }
  }
  return 1;
}







int main()
{
    int maxsize=10;
    int test;
    char buff[200];
    int counter=0;
    char c;
    int i;
    path* array=malloc(maxsize*sizeof(path));
    if(array==NULL) {
        printf("Error allocating memory\n");
        abort();
    }


    FILE* fd=fopen("Wiki-Vote.txt","r");
    if(fd==NULL) {
        printf("Error opening file\n");
        abort();
    }


  while(fgets(buff,200,fd)) {

        c=buff[0];
        if(c=='#') {
            continue;
        }
    sscanf(buff,"%d%d",&array[counter].start,&array[counter].end);
        counter++;
        if(counter==maxsize){
           maxsize=doublesize(&array,maxsize); 
    }

    }

  maxsize=counter;
    counter=0;
    qsort(&array[0],maxsize,sizeof(path),cmp);




  counter=1;
  int nodes=10;
  int* hash=malloc(nodes*sizeof(int));
  if(hash==NULL){
    printf("Error allocating memory\n");
    abort();
  }

for(i=0;i<maxsize;i++){
  if(hash[counter-1]==array[i].start)
    continue;
        hash[counter]=array[i].start;
        counter++;
        if(counter==nodes){
          nodes=hashdoublesize(&hash,nodes);
        }
}
int j;
for(i=0;i<maxsize;i++){
  for(j=0;j<counter;j++){
    if(hash[j]==array[i].end)
      break;
  }
  if(j!=counter)
    continue;
  hash[counter]=array[i].end;
  counter++;
  if(counter==nodes)
    nodes=hashdoublesize(&hash,nodes);
}

nodes=counter;
qsort(&hash[0],nodes,sizeof(int),hashcmp);


  int* arraynodes=malloc(nodes*sizeof(int));
  int* arrayedges=malloc(maxsize*sizeof(int));
  if(arraynodes==NULL||arrayedges==NULL){
    printf("Error allocating memory\n");
    abort();
  }
  int edge_count=maxsize;
  int edge_offset=0;
  for(int i=0;i<nodes;i++){
    int current_node=hash[i];
    arraynodes[i]=edge_offset;
    while(edge_offset<edge_count&& array[edge_offset].start == current_node){
      edge_offset++;
    }
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < edge_count; i++){
    arrayedges[i]=array[i].end;
  }








int x;
  printf("give number to search: "); 
  scanf("%d",&x);
  for(i=0;i<nodes;i++){
    if(x==hash[i]){
      printf("found \n");
      break;
    }
  }
  if(i==nodes){
    printf("not found \n");
    abort();
  }

/*  for(j=arraynodes[i];j<arraynodes[i+1];j++){
    printf("%d\n",arrayedges[j]);
  }*/

  int en=hash[i];
  int st;
  printf("From where would you like to start: ");
  scanf("%d",&st);
  printf("\n");
  int found;
  found=bfs(arraynodes,arrayedges,nodes,st,en);
  if(found){
    printf("Found\n");
  }
  else
    printf("Not found\n");







  free(arraynodes);
  free(arrayedges);
  free(hash);
    fclose(fd);
    free(array);
        return 0;
}
```

Thank you for your time and any help will be apreciated.

Comment: It seems like a perfect time to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code, statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values.

Comment: And the `stack_doublesize` function seems... wrong. Why would you suddenly want to have *two* stacks instead of one? It would make more sense to call `nodesdoublesize` to increase the size of the array pointed to by `num`. In fact, calling `stack_doublesize` will currently lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), as you loop out of bounds of the single `stack` object you initially create. You might also be interested to real about the [`realloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc) function.

Comment: You are right, I did that (and edited) but it still shows the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your `stack_doublesize` function is *very* wrong, and could be a reason behind your problems as using it will lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Currently as shown (as I write this answer), it will basically reallocate a single `stack` structure into an array of *20* `stack` structures. It will then treat the single original `stack` structure as an array of `10` structure, and copy those `10` to the new array. This will of course go out of bounds since you don't have an array of `10` structures, only one single structure.

Furthermore you don't reallocate the memory pointed to by the `stack` structure itself, the `num` member will still be the same. That means you will go out of bounds of this memory as well.

As a solution for these issues I suggest you change your reallocation functions to something like this:

```
// Reallocate a dynamically allocated array, doubling its size
int nodesdoublesize(int **array,int n)
{
    int* new_array = realloc(*array, n * 2 * sizeof *new_array);
    if (new_array == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory\n");
        abort();
    }

    *array = new_array;
    return n * 2;
}

// Reallocate the data of the stack
void stack_doublesize(stack *s)
{
    s->size = nodesdoublesize(&s->num, s->size);
}
```

Change your call to `stack_doublesize` to follow the new funciton.

---

There are probably more errors and problems in your code that I haven't found. I suggest you start by building with extra warnings enabled (`-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic` if using GCC or Clang, and `/W4` if using MSVC), and treat all warnings as errors that you need to fix.